# Show an operator is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$\text { Let }\left\{x_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { be a sequence in a Banach space } X . \text { Fix } 1 \leq p \leq \infty \text { , and suppose that for } \text { every } \mu \in X^{*} \text { we have that } \\ \qquad T(\mu)=\left(\mu\left(x_{n}\right)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{p^{\prime}}$

Then I want to show that $T: X^{*} \rightarrow \ell^{p^{\prime}} \text { is bounded }$.

How to continue from $\|{T(\mu)}\|=\|{\left(\mu\left(x_{n}\right)\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}}\|=(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|\mu(x_i)|^{p^{'}})^{1/{p^{'}}}$ to $\leq C\|\mu\|$?

Any help or hint is appreciated.

Comment: I got a hint says that using uniform boundedness principle, may that helpful?

Comment: What is meant by $p'$?

Comment: $p^{\prime}$ is defined as 1/$p$+1/$p^{\prime}$=1, someone calls it $q$